# Arbitrarily long decomposition into partial fractions.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

$$\int \frac{dx}{x(x+p)(x+2p)(x+3p)...(x+(n-1)p)}= ?$$

I'm trying to solve this integral, and as I usually do in these cases, I break the expression into partial fractions, but I find this case somehow tough, despite the thing that all the factors are liniar, I have no idea on how to find just a bunch of constants. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: There is a great deal of difference between "arbitrarily long" (as in your case) and "infinite". Now to the point: do the cases $n=2,3,4$, then you'll see the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea to calculate it directly, but I guessed and easily verified my answer
$$\int \frac{dx}{x(x+p)(x+2p)(x+3p)...(x+(n-1)p)}= \\
\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n-1}{k-1}\ln|x+k-1|(-1)^{k-1}+C$$

Comment: Can it be done without the Gamma function? I took it from a university preparation calculus book, I don't think this was intended to be solved exclusively using the Gamma function.

Comment: It is okay to use $(n-1)!$ instead of $\Gamma(n)$, virtually, I evaluate it without using Gamma function. I just looked for the pattern and use the sequence from PASCAL triangle to verify my answer.